# iOS Taking Screenshot and automatically attach to iMessage

Tags: ios, nsstring, uiimage

Good day! I just want to ask if how can i Attach a Programatically screenshot image to iMessage?

this is the Screenshot code i use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *screenshotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotimage, nil, nil, nil);
```

now i have this code to programmatically create an iMessage to any of the specified numbers or emails,

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
 [textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
  NSString *messagebody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here's my message"];

     if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
         [textComposer setRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@email.com", nil]];
         [textComposer setBody:messagebody];
         [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];

     } else {
         NSLog(@"Can't Open Text");
     }
```

now, what i've tried is this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
     [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *screenshotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotimage, nil, nil, nil);

     MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
     [textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

     NSString *attachmentmessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here's my Screenshot %@",screenshotimage];




if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
     [textComposer setRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@email.com", nil]];
     [textComposer setBody:attachmentmessage];
    [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];

 } else {
     NSLog(@"Can't Open Text");
 }
```

Yes its automatically creates a preset message, but the Image i've screenshot is not in the attachment? this is the sample Preset message i get

> "Here's my Screenshot UIImage:0x16d9a180>"

Comment: You should use `canSendAttachments` and not `canSendText`. `canSendText` will check whether you can send a SMS, `canSendAttachments` check whether you can send a MMS. Since `MFMessageComposeViewController` will not tell you is iMessage is available you should check for the `canSendAttachments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this

```
NSString *attachmentmessage = @"Here's my Screenshot"];


if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    [textComposer setRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@email.com", nil]];
    [textComposer setBody:attachmentmessage];
    [textComposer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenshotimage,1.0) typeIdentifier:@"public.data" filename:@"image.png"];
    [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This could still fail if the user does not have MMS setup even if iMessage is available. You should use `canSendAttachments`.